# PHP remove everything except letters and a hyphen (-)

Tags: php, regex, filter

I'm making a form that asks for the user's first and last name, and I don't want them entering

```
$heil4
```

I would like them to enter

```
Sheila
```

I know how to filter out everything except letters, but I'm aware that some names can have

```
Sheila-McDonald
```

So how would I remove everything from a string apart from letters and a hyphen?

Comment: Since when do you know someone with a number in their name?

Comment: Point taken (about underscores too probably), but what about non-latin letters?

Comment: Show us what you have now, so we can improve that rather than making something entirely new

Comment: The singer Ke$ha is going to hate your site.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use

```
$s = preg_replace("/[^a-z-]/i", "", $s);
```

or if you want to convert some non-ascii characters to ascii, such as `Jean-Rémy` to `Jean-Remy`, then use

```
$s = preg_replace("/[^a-z-]/i", "", iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $s));
```

Comment: converting non-ascii characters to ascii is not working with the above code

Answer (score 2):

`$new = preg_replace('#[^A-Z-]#iu', '', $data);`

but instead of removing letters (and thus modifying user's input) better validate it
and show an error if the input is not valid. This way the user will know that what he had entered is exactly the value you have

`if(!preg_match('#[A-Z-]#iu', $data)) echo 'invalid';`

Comment: You misuse the class range here: with `[A-z]` all the symbols that are between `Z` and  `a` (such as `[`, for example) won't be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing with nothing, have some fun. that way a name that consists mainly of numbers you can decode ;p

```
$name = '$h3il4-McD0nald';

$find    = array(0,1,3,4,5,6,7,'$');
$replace = array('o','l','e','a','s','g','t','s');
$name = str_replace($find,$replace,$name);

//Sheila-McDonald
echo ucfirst(preg_replace('/[^a-z-]/i', '', $name));
```

Comment: Okay, now when you edit your answer and make correction you came with pretty much same code as I have :)

Comment: ok `/s` means single line, and that was a typo, and `/i` means case insensitive, meaning there would be no use for the A-Z char set, hense i left it out.... thanks for the downvote :)

Comment: Downvote has been removed after you have corrected your answer, if you haven't notice... Also >> some last names begin with a lower case letter, e.g. `von Schack` and such names should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to strip out all non alpha-numeric characters, not including non latin characters, and [prescribed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) [punctuation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

`$strtochange= preg_replace("/[^\s\p{Pd}a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]/",'',$strtochange);`

Note: this will turn `$heil4` into `heil`.